# Disable pinch to zoom in windows 8 cordova app

Tags: html, cordova, windows-8

Having issues with cordova continuing to do pinch zoom on windows 8. Here's the meta tag I'm using which should disable it according to the documentation:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: see if it helps you http://plugreg.com/plugin/lisovin/cordova-wp8-viewport

Comment: Didn't seem to help. Tried installing the plugin, no results. Copied the code from it directly and didnt seem to change anything either. To be fair, that plugin is for windows phone 8, not the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />


    * {
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); /* make transparent link selection, adjust last value opacity 0 to 1.0 */
    }

    body {
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;                /* prevent callout to copy image, etc when tap to hold */
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;             /* prevent webkit from resizing text to fit */
        -webkit-user-select: none;                  /* prevent copy paste, to allow, change 'none' to 'text' */
        /*background-color:#E4E4E4;*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with this issue, the solution (apart from the viewport meta tags) is to add this to your CSS:

```
body{
    touch-action: pan-y; /* prevent touch actions except vertical scroll */
}
```